# What's the difference between Pathfinder and Pathfinder Chronicles?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I was poking around the Paizo website, and noticed that there are minis for Pathfinder, and others for Pathfinder Chronicles.  What's the difference between the two?  I couldn't see anything in my research.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They try to explain the various product lines on [the Paizo Pathfinder family page here](http://paizo.com/pathfinder).
Pathfinder Chronicles is actually a deprecated name, it's now called Pathfinder Campaign Setting for clarity.

- [Pathfinder](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG) - the core game products, mainbooks mostly
- [Pathfinder Adventure Path](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/adventurePath) - the big 6-part linked campaigns
- [Pathfinder Modules](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/modules) - the smaller traditional adventure modules, more standalone, only sometimes loosely linked to others
- [Pathfinder Campaign Setting](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/campaignSetting) - was: Pathfinder Chronicles, mostly GM-focused setting info.  Worldbooks, citybooks, maps, NPCs.  Often heavier on fluff than crunch.
- [Pathfinder Player Companion](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/companion) - was: Pathfinder Companion, mostly player-focused guides with additional crunch and player-safe setting info for a given race or country.
- Also Tales (novels), [Miniatures](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/pathfinderMiniatures) (minis), and Organized Play (adventure scenarios for tournament play).

A lot of this was somewhat confusing and has undergone a couple revs of rebranding, so when you see "Pathfinder Chronicles Mini" it probably is just a legacy term from before there was a "Pathfinder Minis" line and they were lumped into Chronicles.

Comment: Cool!  You answered the question I asked, and the one I didn't know to ask until you answered my first question!

Comment: I aim to please :-)

Answer (score 2):

Pathfinder Chronicles was simply the Pathfinder RPG Lore content owned by Paizo before Pathfinder was released as a standalone RPG (It was third party material for D&D3.5e). As such, "Chronicles" is often used to refer to this legacy content, at least in the context you're asking about.